# Python windows 11: new file has old creation date

Tags: python, operating-system, windows-11

I have python script that a) generates data to be saved in a new file, b) looks whether a file with the same name already exists, c) renames the old file using os.rename if it does exist, d) and saves the data to a new file.

The problem is that the new file has "Date Created" equal to that of the old file. I.e. apparently, Windows "remembers" file name + creation date combination, and uses this remembered creation date for a new file with the remembered name.

Here is a working example:

```
from os import path, rename
from datetime import datetime

f_name = "file.txt"

if path.exists(f_name) :
    file_mtime = path.getmtime(f_name)            
    mt_stamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(file_mtime).strftime("%y%m%d-%H%M%S")
    file_name, file_extension = path.splitext(f_name)
    new_f_name = file_name + "-" + mt_stamp + file_extension 
    rename(f_name, new_f_name)

with open(f_name, 'w') as wfile:
    wfile.write("test text")
```

Run it a few times, and all generated files will have the same creation date despite being in fact created at different times.

Here is a screenshot of what I get after running the code four times:

https://i.imgur.com/HlQE4jU.png

(I don't have enough reputation to post images)

If there is no old file with the same name, creation date of a new file is correct.

If before running the script you just deleted manually a file with the same name, the newly saved file will have creation date of the deleted file.

Is there a way to force the new file to have its own correct creation date?

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Added a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes, Windows does that just because the operation you're doing is so common. It's considered a feature not a bug.

Comment: i have run this three times and each time got a different `creation date` and `modified date` for all of the different files.  ie. the were all created at different times.  `windows 10`...   is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: For a more detailed explanation of what I said earlier, see [The Old New Thing: The apocryphal history of file system tunnelling](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050715-14/?p=34923).

Comment: it appear at though the *tunnelling cache time is 15 seconds* but can be adjusted from the default time of 15 seconds....

Answer (score 0):

i run the code exactly as it is and get this:

[image]

Each file has a different creation date (and a matching modified date) as expected.

I run the code on `windows 10`.

Comment: here is what I get on windows 11:

https://i.imgur.com/HlQE4jU.png

In your screenshot, the 2nd and 3rd files have creation date later than modification date, which is even weirder.

Comment: @ScudBee very interesting. i can try on a windows 11 machine in a couple of days time and let you know (assuming no replies before then). I actually like the code you wrote !!

Comment: my first suggestion might be to use `full path names`. Let me know what happens when you try that.... (also, feel free to edit the answer if that does work).

Comment: adding `f_name = path.abspath(f_name)` line after `f_name = "file.txt"` did not change anything -- and it shouldn't according to the piece @Mark linked. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @ScudBee,  I notice that what you observe in `windows 11` is true. And that the behaviour is different in `windows 10`... and as MR posted in the last comment, it is a feature of windows 11.   Presumably a hack would be to create a temporary file, name to this, then delete the temp file and write the new file (rather clunky, but a solution).

Comment: there is a tunnelling cash time of 15 seconds. You could put a write delay for this period, or adjust it:  https://web.archive.org/web/20160410012540/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/172190

Comment: Yes the delay of at least 15 sec does the trick, but unfortunately this solution is not practical in my case.

Comment: I don't like the solution in particular either. it is more a feature of the (`windows 11`) operating system. And more importantly, it answers your (our) question !!